# Alter table to add default utc time value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `insert_tbl`. I want to alter it to add a new column called `ddate_insert` with data type `datetime` with default value of utctime.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I would recommend to use either `DATE` (if you only need the date - no time), or then `DATETIME2(3)` if you need both date and time portions. Try to avoid `DATETIME` - it has its share of issues (date range only from 1/1/1753, accuracy only 3.33ms - not 1ms) - so try to use the **more appropriate**, more convenient datatypes SQL Server **2008** and newer give you!

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE insert_tbl ADD ddate_insert datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getutcdate()
```